# Invalid Syntax in python

Tags: python

```
grade = int(input("Enter Grade: "))

def finalgrade(grade):  

if grade >= 90 and <= 100:
   return "A"

elif grade >=80 and <= 89:
    return "B"
else:
    return "F"
```

Complains `invalid syntax in = sign before 100`

Any help will greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're not explicitly comparing `100` or `89` **to** anything. This is the better syntax:

```
if 90 <= grade <= 100:
    return "A"
elif 80 <= grade <= 89:
    return "B"
else:
    return "F"
```

But closer to how you wrote it, you would need to include `grade` in both comparisons:

```
if grade >= 90 and grade <= 100:
     return "A"
elif grade >=80 and grade <= 89:
    return "B"
else:
    return "F"
```

As an aside, you might want to consider the possibility of `grade=89.5` and change your range to `80 <= grade < 90`, using `<` instead of `<=`

Comment: Thank you , this works, But I have another problem, now code prompts me to enter the grade, when I enter 99 it comes out to command prompt instead of returning  'A'. Can please tell me what is wrong in my code

Comment: you need to actually call the `finalgrade` function, as `print finalgrade(grade)`. be sure to do that at the end of your script, *after* the `def` for the function, or it won't be defined yet

Answer (score 0):

`elif grade >=80 and <= 89:` should be `elif grade >=80 and grade <= 89:`, and `if grade >= 90 and <= 100:` should be `if grade >= 90 and grade <= 100:`

Answer (score 0):

`elif grade >=80 and <= 89:` is wrong; there should be something being compared to the 89. I'm guessing you mean `elif grade >=80 and grade <= 89:`. Same goes for the 90-100 part.

Answer (score 0):

Python won't implicitly use `grade` as the left operand of `<=`. You need to write it twice, or use comparison chaining:

```
if 90 <= grade <= 100:
```

(which doesn't work in most languages, but does in Python.)

Answer (score 0):

if grade >= 90 and grade <= 100:

You left off the second grade.